# How should I send a Postgis geometry data? WKT or WKB?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, jts

I need to do an integration between two PostGIS databases using Java. I will receive a JSON file and each line of it represents a record of a table. Some of the tables have geometry columns.

Should I receive this geometry data as PostGIS WKB hex representation or as a WKT? The PostGIS representation is more compact and JTS can parse it in both ways, so it seems that it would be best to send the data in that format, but most of the examples I see, the integration is done via WKT, so I'm really not sure about the best approach.

Should I send the data as WKB or WKT?

Answer (score 0):

There are really no differences on how you send it. That will largely depend on bandwidth requirements. If this is a web app, you're probably going to want the smaller representation.

But you could also use JSON. JTS probably has something to import a geometry from JSON as well.

Whatever you choose, just keep an eye to some of the specs regarding 3d geometries. Some parsers will ditch the z component to match the spec (I had a similar problem with Django years ago, but it was actually a bug).

Answer (score 0):

One option to look at would be to use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html) to directly query the other PostGIS database instead of an export and then import process.

From the docs:

> dblink executes a query (usually a SELECT, but it can be any SQL statement that returns rows) in a remote database.

So you can send a query from one database that would look something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dblink('connection_string_to_other_db', 'sql_query');
```

You would then receive those rows in the database you ran the query from.

I don't know if that is what your looking for but it is one pretty straightforward way to get data from one PostgreSQL DB to another.